# NoClassDefFoundError when trying to load class

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, jar, drools

I am getting a `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` when trying to instantiate some class

I will try to simplify the structure of my projects: I have 2 jar files A (with a.class inside) and B (with b.class) I am trying to instantiate a 'b' class inside 'a' code. `JAR A` is dependant on  `JAR B`. `JAR A` is a regular JAR file which is located in application/lib and `JAR B` is packaged as an `EJB_JAR`.

I am using `glassfish` and `J2EE` with `maven` I am new to J2EE and I have tried to look up a little for it. I have figured out it might be a class loaders issue, as the Classloader that loads classes from lib ( A) is the Ancestor of the Classloader that loads EARs WARs and EJB_JARs hence because of visibility issues I cannot load class 'b' from 'a'

Also, when I'm trying invoke (using the "expression evaluator") `Class.forName("com.package.SomeClass")`   in the debugger from classes located in Jar-A to load class in JAR-A I get a class, but when I try to load classes located in Jar-B I get the `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` exception.

The thing is, that the passed EJB in the constructor has all the EJB fields properly, so I thought it should work, and, everything was compiled successfully.

How do I solve this problem?

The weirdest thing:
I am using drools which resides in JAR_A and JAR_A has some regular class which tries to call b.class (in JAR_B)

calling b.class from a.class doesnt work,
but calling b.class directly from a rule (which got b.class from CommandFactory.newSetGlobal("Bclass",b))works just fine.
How Could it be?

when I pass it as an Object from JAR_B it works and invokates fine.

Comment: Is maven concerned in the whole issue?

Comment: Yes. But it looks like there is no problem with the dependencies, and all classes that should be in the jar are provided properly.

Comment: You've got two copies of a specific JAR so without more information, can't help much! You can use maven to find out where you have copies of dependencies

Comment: do you mean *mvn  dependency:tree>*?
I have run it and all jars brought by dependencies are fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Recap

You say:

> I am trying to instantiate a 'b' class inside 'a' code. JAR A is dependant on JAR B. JAR A is a regular JAR file which is located in `application/lib` and JAR B is packaged as an EJB_JAR.

From what I understand, you have a `pom.xml` to build jar A, which states that jar B is its `<dependency/>`.

Then I see two possible cases for your deployment scenarios: you are either deploying the jars to the application server as an EAR, where jar A is contained inside this EAR as a library and jar B is a deployment inside it, or you are trying to use B from another, unrelated application.

In either deployment case, this is an error, but it might be due to expressing your dependencies incorrectly, or accessing the EJB incorrectly.

## Nested Deployment case

If this is a nested deployment, where jar A is contained in the EAR as a library, you have a dependency expression problem. An EAR library *can not* have a dependency on the EAR itself, it can only be the other way around. After all, this *is* the definition of a library, right? :)

You have to refactor your application to match the use case you are trying to implement here. For more info, see the excellent [Patterns of Modular Architecture](https://dzone.com/refcardz/patterns-modular-architecture) RefCard from [DZone](http://dzone.com/).

## Application client case

If what you are writing is an isolated (might even be a standalone) client that is going to invoke some operations on the EJB, what you should do is create an *interface* (local or remote, depending on how you are deploying the client) and package it with the client application and your EJB.

Then use a JNDI lookup in your client application to obtain a reference to the remote EJB and use it via the interface:

```
Context foo = new InitialContext(remoteJndiServiceProperties);
MyBeanInterface bar = (MyBeanInterface)foo.lookup("com.mycompany.MyBeanInterface");
bar.doStuff();
```

The remote JNDI registry properties and your bean's business interface name have to be expressed properly, of course. See the [EJB FAQ for Glassfish](https://glassfish.java.net/javaee5/ejb/EJB_FAQ.html) for more info.

It is even simpler if your client is running in the same deployment unit - you can just use the `@EJB` annotation in that case and inject a *no-interface* EJB reference.

For more information on standalone clients with GlassFish, see the [Developing Application Clients with ACC](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2418/beakv.html) guide which covers all possible deployment scenarios.

## Some theory behind this

Run the application in a debugger (or look at the heap dump taken while your client is invoking methods on the EJB, passing it objects as parameters).

What you will see is that the EJB container (that is, your EJB) is not working with the actual class you think it is, but rather with something called *a static proxy* class, which is generated on the fly by the container.

Because of this, when you invoke the `instanceof` operator inside the EJB, checking if the class you're working with is of the correct type, it will evaluate to `true`, but when you try to typecast it, you will get a `ClassCastException`.

This is required by the EJB specification and there is not much you can do about it, except pass the objects not as references, but rather as serialized data (which is going to cost you).

It works the other way around, too, because the container must be able to *intercept* anything done to the EJB from outside of it, and react (such as unauthorized use of restricted methods, transaction handling, etc.).

BTW, a lot of what you are describing above is illegal. ;)

Manually loading classes using `Class.forName()` inside an EJB container, for example - the EJB container should manage the lifecycle of your objects and anything you can not obtain using a factory method, or even better, using "compatible" mechanisms such as CDI *producers* and *dependency injection*, should be passed to your EJBs as a parameter.

What is also questionable is the way you try to pass an instance of the EJB to an application running outside of the container. If you need to access your EJBs to invoke methods on them, you should do it by means of an EJB client, in your case most probably through a *remote interface*.

Also, look up the definition of *classloader hell* if you still want to pursue your approach - you might want to start with [this article](http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue180.html), but I guess it's just as good as any other.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! 
 I am running it in the debugger and a weird thing happens:
when going over the invocation with step by step it throughs the exception as usual.
but when evaluating it (with intellij's expression evaluator in debugger) it succeeds.
Can you elaborate about what's illegal?is it invoking ejb method from pojo or trying to load class from another jar? or both?

Comment: I added it to the answer due to the length limitation in comments, sorry. ;)

Comment: Is the ejb packaging type matters?

Comment: You're not providing enough information to answer this. What is the structure of your application(s)? What container are you running them in? How do you instantiate the EJB and how do you start your client application?

Comment: I have added some more information.
Is that enough to get the general idea?

Comment: Thanks, Yuria, yes, it explains a lot. Actually, you have partially answered your own question, but still - check the answer where I added some additional info on it.